# Articles or White Papers on .NET frameworks

Tags: .net

I was wondering if someone could point me in the direction to some articles or white papers containing information on the newest release of the .NET Framework.  Having a history of the fixes between releases of the .NET Framework would be helpful too.  I have noticed that there are no "release notes" but I really need this information to research some issues we have been having with our web app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia actually does a [very good job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) with that question.  Also, check out [this talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL16/) by Anders Hejlsberg from PDC.  He goes into 4.0 and gives a little preview of stuff further down the road as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the .NET Framework 3.0 [release notes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb188202.aspx).